# Windows Phone 8 - Memory Profiler Missing

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

When I start WP8 app analysis(debug, Start Windows Phone Application Analysis) two out of three options are missing:

1. Monitoring (missing)
2. Profiling Execution
3. Memory Profiling (missing)

I hope I'm just missing something stupid but any help would be appreciated.

My screen looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F0iP.png

The following article details what is should look like.:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj215908(v=vs.105).aspx

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One explanantion is that Direct3D apps don't have Monitoring and Memory Profiling options - [Profiling Direct3D Apps for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662995%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Startappprofiling).